# what should I do so that gsm location is automaticallically detected and write function is called?

Tags: android

I simply want to do if the gsm location is updated, write  `cellid`  to the database. For this wish, I have tried to implement service class, as you can see at below. The question what should I do so that gsm location is automaticallically detected and write function namely C(), job is write cellid to the database is called ?

My start work ;

```
public class GpsCell extends Service{
TelephonyManager tel;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    tel = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();

}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a `PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION` listener to get the cellid updates

```
public class GpsCellLogger extends Service{
  TelephonyManager tel;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    tel = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    tel.listen(myListener , PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION);

    GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();


  }
  PhoneStateListener myListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
      public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation p_CellLocation)
      {
        //write to database
      }
 }

}
```

Comment: Should I change manifest file ? Where should Registration  be done ? Thanks

Comment: The registration done in the line `tel.listen(this, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION);`

Comment: Thanks for replay. Do I need add intent-filter to the manifest?

Comment: No, just remember to stop the listener when you do not need to receive cellid updates anymore. You are welcome.

Comment: It gives a error `PhoneStateListener cannot be resolved to a type`. Why ? IS it built in listener ?

Comment: yes it is, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it is a class, just create another class that extends it.

Comment: I thought I should create external class. I did but I have took error. Anyway thanks for updates. There seems no error.